# Creating Emacs TAGS file

Tags: debian, emacs

I am working through the "Emacs Lisp Intro" book within Emacs 23.4.1 on Debian Wheezy (CrunchBang Waldorf).

Section 4.1 discusses the `find-tags` command and the `TAGS` file. Instructions are included to build/install the `TAGS` file if necessary.

How do I do this in Debian? The folders mentioned are not present on my system and I cannot locate a `TAGS` file.

I'm not sure that I have the source of Emacs installed? I installed it using `apt-get`. My `sources.list` file does not include any `deb-src` lines, if that is relevant.

Comment: Try `apt-get install ctags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This required installing the `emacs23-el` package for the Emacs source code and then building the `TAGS` file in `/usr/share/emacs/23.4/lisp` with:

```
$ etags *.el.gz
```

as these files are in `.gz` format. However, `find-tags` cannot read these and attempts to read the `.el` file. This can be solved, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420924/emacs-find-tag-has-trouble-with-el-gz-files), by adding the following to `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'jka-compr)
```

After this, it is possible to enter `find-tags` and then `mark-whole-buffer`, as discussed in the example in the "Emacs Lisp Intro" mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
daniel@protein:~$ apt-file search {ctags,etags} | grep ctags | grep /usr/bin
emacs23-bin-common: /usr/bin/ctags.emacs23
exuberant-ctags: /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant
```

I'm on ubuntu, but I'm reasonably sure they're in the same packages.

To create the `TAGS` file you'll want something like this:

```
$ find . -type f -iname "*.php" | xargs ctags --declarations
$ find . -type f -iname "*.ctp" | xargs ctags --lang="php" --declarations --append
```

Both commands have very similar arguments, but check the man page to make sure.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the problem lay elsewhere, as detailed in my answer.

Comment: No worries, and nice work on the real solution.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 (via `dnf` [formerly `yum` {much like `apt-get`}]) on Fedora 22 and what worked for me was navigating to `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp` and running:

```
etags *.el.gz
```

Nothing further was required for me to follow along with the tutorial.